# Pass a Struct to a function and input data in it

Tags: c++, c

I have an array of structures and i try to pass an element to input data, i want the array to be modified so i pass it as a pointer but something is going wrong when i input data by scanf so the program is't running

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define n 50

struct Student
{
    char *FirstName;
    char *LastName;
    double Grade;
};

void StudentData( struct Student st );
void EnterStudentData ( struct Student *st );
void AddStudent ( struct Student *st, int *size );

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    struct Student students[n];

    AddStudent(students, &size);
    StudentData(students[0]);

    return 0;
}

void StudentData( struct Student st )
{
    printf("FirstName: %s\tPrenume: %s\tMedia: %.2lf", st.FirstName, st.LastName, st.Grade);
}

void EnterStudentData ( struct Student *st )
{
    printf("FirstName : ");
    scanf_s("%s", &st->FirstName);
    printf("LastName : ");
    scanf_s("%s", &st->LastName);
    printf("Grade : ");
    scanf_s("%lf", &st->Grade);
}

void AddStudent ( struct Student *st, int *size )
{
    EnterStudentData(&st[*size]);
    ++(*size);
}
```

Comment: You never allocate memory for `FirstName` or `LastName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not allocated any memory for `FirstName` or `LastName`

Try this:

```
char FirstName[n];
char LastName[n];
```

But if you're using C++, just use a `string`

**Edit:**

Since you tagged your question with C++, here's a C++ solution with `string` and `vector`:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Student
{
  string FirstName;
  string LastName;
  double Grade;
};

void StudentData( const Student& _st );
void EnterStudentData ( Student& _st );
void AddStudent ( vector<Student>& st, int& size );

int main()
{
  int size = 0;
  vector<Student> students;

  AddStudent(students, size);
  StudentData(students[0]);

  return 0;
}

void StudentData( const Student& _st )
{
   cout << "FirstName: " << _st.FirstName << "\t"
        << "LastName: " << _st.LastName << "\t";
   cout.setf(ios::fixed,ios::floatfield);
   cout.precision(2);
   cout << "Grade: "  << _st.Grade << endl;
}

void EnterStudentData (Student& _st )
{
  cout << "FirstName : ";
  cin >> _st.FirstName;
  cout << "LastName : ";
  cin >> _st.LastName;
  cout << "Grade : ";
  cin >> _st.Grade;
}

void AddStudent (vector<Student>& _st, int& _size )
{
  Student next;
  EnterStudentData(next);
  _st.push_back(next);
  ++_size;
}
```

Comment: You are right i have not noticed it, i was searching the mistake for hours, thanks.

Comment: @user2205211: I edited the post with a full C++ solution (your question was tagged with C++, so I thought it would be okay)

Comment: Thanks for this example, it will be helpful

Answer (score -2):

with scanf_s("%s", &st->FirstName) , your getting the address of st and using the -> operator on it. Try with &(st->Grade)

Comment: what's the line that crashes ? if it's on the string, AndyG is right, you need to allocate them.